# Is there a way to go to the next green or yellow margin area in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

The green and yellow margin areas are changed source code. Is there a keystroke you can use to go forward or backward to the next line that's green or yellow?

Comment: *How large are your code files?*  The mouse wheel works quite admirably for me.

Comment: Eh. The one I'm working on right now is about 5000 lines.

Comment: git diff is useful for any size files... right?

Comment: Is there a reason that file is so large?  SRP, y'know.

Comment: Because I'm not a very good programmer?

Comment: It also might just be an archaic project, if it was brownfield project it would be irrelevant how many lines there are.

Comment: I don't think there's a shortcut key, but you always have the ability to just left click (hold) in the scrollbar to bring the cursor to where you want to go. You could also drag the scroll bar itself (I personally think dragging is the easiest).